# How to see what clients of lan doing on the internet

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, proxy, squid

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server with routing, firewall, dhcp, dns caching. Is it possible to see what clients doing on internet, most importantly what sites are they visiting? It can be done by proxy (which I have - Squid and its analyzer Lightsquid), but is it possible to do it without proxy? To have some overview or survey over what people do on my network? I mean in the sence of lightsquid, some kind of "database" or long term overview, where I can actually view their activity on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see actually communication data (i.e. what your users are posting on facebook), however using Wireshark you can see incoming and outcoming http & https requests, and you could tell what website they are looking at. 
Happy spying!
- The Exp3rt
(https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Hi, I know about wireshark, but I acutally mean some kind of long term overview. I edited my original post, to make it more clear.

Comment: Wireshark will run indefinitely, as far as I'm aware. How is what you want different to what Wireshark can give?

Comment: Is it possible to implement wireshark on text based server? Lightsquid works the way that it takes log files from squid in some set interval, and makes simple overview (accesible by putting your server ip in browsers address line) what ip  went on what www page when, how many times etc. Is it possible to do this in wireshark? I always thought that its only for "on the fly" use...

Comment: Is that a way how to watch your network? How the network administrators do it? I don't want to be blind :-)